# Trigger apps script when a new line is added to extract a number from a string

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, gmail, ifttt

I am currently using an IFTTT trigger to add a new line to a spreadsheet when an email arrives with a certain label which works great, however, on the new line that's imported I need to then extract a number from a string in a cell.

Right now I need to copy this formula into a cell in the newly imported line to get the number I need from it: =IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(C5,"[0-9]+"))

Can anyone point me in the right direction to achieve this with a script that runs on edit to avoid having to keep copying this formula down?

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your formula in `ARRAYFORMULA` and give it a range to watch:

`=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(C5:C,"[0-9]+")))`

`ARRAYFORMULA` won't overwrite cells with data (you'll get an `#ERROR`). I'd test it in the next column to make sure you're getting the data you want, then remove your current extraction column. The formula will watch the entire range for the length of the sheet.